# How to use a webview in a fixed size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-webview

I need a page which show web contents in a fixed `width` and `height`.
I put a webview inside a xml file with a height of 200px,but while loading that page,it directly redirect to default browser view.
While press the back button in the phone,it redirect to the original page,then the webview shows nothing.

in my xml file

```
 <WebView  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200px" android:id="@+id/wvbrowser" />
```

in code

```
  WebView wvbrowser;
    wvbrowser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvbrowser);
    wvbrowser.loadUrl("http://www.orkut.com");
```

So tell me where I am Wrong? and how to show WebView in FIXED size?

Comment: how to type '<' sign in emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

create a separate class.

```
public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in your activity use this.

```
WebView wvbrowser;
wvbrowser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvbrowser);
wvbrowser.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
wvbrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wvbrowser.loadUrl("http://www.orkut.com");
```

Comment: its working fine.what is the working of the above code?,i mean what does the HelloWebViewClient class ???

Comment: for more information go through this link. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: this code is not working.it is a button click event which re-size two widget.while rezising second widget it throws an exeption.`public void onClick(View v)
{
 if(btcode==v)
 {
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1=wvbrowser.getLayoutParams();
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams params2=wvbrowser.getLayoutParams();
  params1.height=200;
  params2.height=5;
  wvbrowser.setLayoutParams(params1);
  txtcode.setLayoutParams(params2);
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView,the default Android Browser handles the Intent to view a web page, because your Activity isn't technically enabled to do so. You need to override the WebViewClient class and enable your webview Activity to handle its own URL requests.

```
setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

The above line creates a WebViewClient that will load any URL selected from this WebView into the same WebView.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

The shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String) method is passed the current WebView and the URL requested, so all it needs to do is load the URL in the given view. Returning true says that the method has handled the URL and the event should not propagate.

Comment: how to type '<' Character in emulator?i just type from my keyboard.but it shows ':'.